# Why is there an error: "File "stdin1", line 1, invaild syntax"

Tags: python-3.x

Code:

```
def profile(name, age, lang1,lang2,lang3, lang4, lang5):
    print("이름 : {0}\t나이 : {1}\t".format(name,age), end="")
    print(lang1,lang2,lang3,lang4,lang5)
```

SyntaxError: invalid syntax

> > > C:/Users/man/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38-32/python.exe "c:/Users/man/Desktop/python work space/edu.py"
> > > File "", line 1
> > > C:/Users/man/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38-32/python.exe "c:/Users/man/Desktop/python work space/edu.py"

I don't know how to fix it please help me.

Comment: It's working fine in my system

Comment: Could you provide more information? I works fine in my system too.

Comment: when i close visual studio code and restart, it works well. so i think its cause is my setting of visual studio code. but i don't know why it happen. so i want to take some advise about that.  i think i debugged my file with "control + F5" and after debugging, it happened.  what did i mistake in my visual studio code setting